# How to clear folder metadata?

Tags: windows, reset, user-folders

In Windows there are several types of folder types: General Items, Documents, Pictures, Music, Videos. User can apply any of them to a folder.

I have a bunch of folders across the filesystem and I want to reset their folder type all at once. Depending on folder's content, Windows will automatically choose the proper folder type for all folders. That's what I need.

I thought that the folder info about folder type was stored in registry, but even after windows reinstalling, folder types on folders didn't reset.

Comment: Run Admin Tools, Disk Cleanup and see what there is to clean up. Look at settings and type in Disk Cleanup to also look for recommendations.   Disk Cleanup (Admin Tools) is easy to run

Comment: @John idk why, but it works with disk C (system), but doesn't with disk D

Comment: Disk Cleanup works on my D: Drive (desktop computer)

Comment: @John woah! Please, can you test the next thing?: create folder on disk D and put there several pictures, then select type of the folder to 'music'. Then use Disk Cleanup on D and check the type of the folder. Is it 'pictures' or 'music'? Please, help!

Comment: It definitely runs on Drive D (Windows 11) and allows selection of folders (just like drive C)  You would need to test from there